# (SQL) Get friends where user and friends are in 2 different tables

Tags: php, sql, join, select

I've got 2 tables: users & friends. I want to show each profile picture of the friends of the logged user, but loggedUser-friends match is in a different table (which is friends) than the one that contains the URI to the profile pictures (which is users).

My query now looks like this:

```
 SELECT profile_picture FROM users WHERE
```

And now I have to complete the WHERE clause:

friend's table schema is the following:

```
id | user_id | friend_id
```

friends table's sample data:

```
1 | pino20 | sebo14
```

while users' table schema is

```
id | user_id | profile_picture
```

users table's sample data:

```
1 | pino20 | pino20/profile.jpg
```

Comment: You might want to add sample data for both tables to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added

Comment: do you want all friends of logged user or a specific friend?

Comment: need table data so member understand properly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below query you get your frends userid and their profile picture.

```
select user_id , profile_picture from users WHERE user_id in( select friend_id from friends where user_id=$your_userid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using joins. It should look like this:

EDIT:
SELECT user.profile_picture,user_friend.profile_picture
FROM user
JOIN friend ON user.user_id = friend.user_id
left join user user_friend on user_friend.friend_id=friend.user_id -- left join since we don't want to drop records if there is no match

Comment: Now my query looks like 

SELECT users.profile_picture FROM users join friends on users.user_id="Pino20" but it returns profile picture for Pino20 and not from friends of Pino20

Answer (score 0):

Above result can be achieved using join

```
SELECT NT.profile_picture  FROM users AS NT JOIN friends  AS FR ON FR.id = NT.id
```